# ImportError: No module named ex47.game (and yes, I have an __init__.py file *AND* I tried all that PYTHONPATH stuff

Tags: python, import, importerror

So I'm trying to finish the "Learn Python the Hard Way" exercise 47, and I created the skeleton directory and created the files in the exercise to do the automated tests. However, when I try to run the ex47_tests.py, I get this little gem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex47_tests.py", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ex47.game
```

So I went back and checked my directories to see if I had an **init**.py file in the same directory that the "game.py" file was in (it's there), and discarded the possibility of a missing **init** file. Tried to run it again, and no doing. Then, I went online and looked up the problem (By the way, that dude who wrote that LPTHW book is, umm, quite lacking when it comes to teaching details that you really need to know, and his teaching really starts to fall apart from Chapter 42 onwards), and I read about using the various PYTHONPATH methods to get PYTHONPATH to look for the file in the ex47 folder. I tried putting in "PYTHONPATH=. python tests/ex47_tests.py", and I still got that error. Then I tried putting in the alternate "python -m tests.ex47_tests" line. Still, no dice. As a final resort, I tried to look at code from people who completed the exercise, and looked over the code in the book, and double/triple-checked it against my code, and I saw no differences.

So my question is, how exactly do I get Python to actually take the blindfold off and see that there actually *IS* a file called "game.py" in the directory "ex47" and get it to import it when I run the ex47_tests file? I've tried just about every answer related to the subject, and nothing.

Here's my directory structure, for reference:

```
bin docs ex47 setup.py tests

./bin:

./docs:

./ex47:
game.py  game.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc

./tests:
ex47_tests.py  ex47_tests.py~  ex47_tests.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc
```

And here is the snippet of code calling the game file:

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex47.game import Room
```

If anyone can help me get past this (and maybe understand why this error keeps popping up when it seems like it has no reason to), I would really appreciate it.

P.S: I also tried running the "nosetests" from the project directory, and sometimes it would work (but in less time than the exercise specified), and sometimes it would give an error saying it couldn't import the game.py file. But no matter what the nosetest, I still can't get the ex47_tests.py file to import the game file.

Comment: What directory are you running your script from.

Comment: I'm running the nosetests from the project directory (the one with the bin, docs, ex47, and tests folders), and I'm trying to run the ex47_tests.py file from the tests directory. I tried to run the ex47_tests.py file from the ex47 directory and the project directory, but it didn't work

Comment: SO I solved my problem. Apparently, the way to use PYTHONPATH to get it to read everything in the directory is to be in the directory above where all the files are (the project directory, in this case), and type in "export PYTHONPATH=." Basically, set the PYTHONPATH to "."

Comment: Nice! Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

By request, I'm going to re-post this in the form of an answer.

SO I solved my problem. Apparently, the way to use PYTHONPATH to get it to read everything in the directory is to be in the directory above where all the files are (the project directory, in this case), and type in "export PYTHONPATH=." Basically, set the PYTHONPATH to "."

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested for Windows did not work for me, so I replaced the top two lines of ex47_tests.py with the following four lines:

- import sys
- sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\Users\User\Test\projects\ex47\ex47')
- import game
- from nose.tools import *
- from game import Room

This appears to have resolved any issues with the nosetests etc.