# LPTHW Ex: 47 ImportError due to PythonPath

Tags: python, powershell, importerror

[ImportError: No module named ex47.game (and yes, I have an __init__.py file *AND* I tried all that PYTHONPATH stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188817/importerror-no-module-named-ex47-game-and-yes-i-have-an-init-py-file-and/23981178#23981178)

I am having the exact same issue as specterace in the question above but in Win7.
I verified my code and structure of my directories, then I put the following into PowerShell

$env:PYTHONPATH = "$env:PYTHONPATH;."

I tried this in both the "project" directory and the "ex47" directory, neither work.
I still get the

ImportError: No module named ex47.game

I need a PowerShell equivalent of "export PYTHONPATH=."

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: So this has nothing to do with PowerShell?

Comment: @AustinFrench Well, I'm looking for the PowerShell command that will set my PythonPath; the PowerShell equivalent of "export PYTHONPATH=." which can be typed in the directory above the directory with all of the files.

Answer (score 0):

The author mentions to copy skeleton directory to a project named ex47.
Within this skeleton, there is a NAME folder . The author asks us to rename it to ex47.
Then when he mentions to create ex47/game.py he means this second ex47 that was initially NAME. 
create your game.py file in this second ex47 and retry.